# eucalyptus node controllers on Centos

Tags: eucalyptus

I have used the Eucalyptus faststart ISO (3.4.2) to set up a frontend controller and 5 node controllers.  The problem that I am having is that the faststart ISO installation of the frontend system only allows you to enter 5 ip addresses for node controllers. I have 4 more machines that I want to be node controllers but when I try to register them I get this screen when I run the euca-describe-services --all command.  Note the additional nodes showing up as "DISABLED".

`[root@frontend1 sbin]# euca-describe-services --all
SERVICE loadbalancing   loadbalancing   10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/LoadBalancing  arn:euca:eucalyptus:loadbalancing:loadbalancing:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE reporting       bootstrap       10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Reporting  arn:euca:bootstrap::reporting:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE dns             eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Dns        arn:euca:eucalyptus::dns:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE component       bootstrap       10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Component  arn:euca:bootstrap::component:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE cloudwatch      cloudwatch      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/CloudWatch arn:euca:eucalyptus:cloudwatch:cloudwatch:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE autoscaling     autoscaling     10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/AutoScaling    arn:euca:eucalyptus:autoscaling:autoscaling:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE notifications   eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Notifications  arn:euca:eucalyptus::notifications:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE jetty           eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Jetty      arn:euca:eucalyptus::jetty:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE db              eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      postgresql://10.162.12.1:8777/eucalyptus?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.eucalyptus.postgresql.PostgreSQLSSLSocketFactory   arn:euca:eucalyptus::db:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE configuration   eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Configuration  arn:euca:eucalyptus::configuration:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE eucalyptus      eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Eucalyptus arn:euca:eucalyptus:::10.162.12.1/
SERVICE bootstrap       bootstrap       10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Empyrean   arn:euca:bootstrap:::10.162.12.1/
SERVICE ldap            eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Ldap       arn:euca:eucalyptus::ldap:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE tokens          eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Tokens     arn:euca:eucalyptus::tokens:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE properties      bootstrap       10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Properties arn:euca:bootstrap::properties:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.10    DISABLED    40      http://10.162.12.10:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC    arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.10/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.2     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.2:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.2/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.3     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.3:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.3/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.4     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.4:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.4/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.5     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.5:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.5/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.7     DISABLED    40      http://10.162.12.7:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.7/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.8     DISABLED    40      http://10.162.12.8:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.8/
SERVICE node            CLUSTER01       10.162.12.9     DISABLED    40      http://10.162.12.9:8775/axis2/services/EucalyptusNC arn:euca:bootstrap:CLUSTER01:node:10.162.12.9/
SERVICE storage         CLUSTER01       sc_01           ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Storage    arn:euca:eucalyptus:CLUSTER01:storage:sc_01/
SERVICE walrus          walrus          walrus          ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Walrus     arn:euca:bootstrap:walrus:walrus:walrus/
SERVICE imaging         imaging         10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Imaging    arn:euca:bootstrap:imaging:imaging:10.162.12.1/
SERVICE cluster         CLUSTER01       cc_01           ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8774/axis2/services/EucalyptusCC arn:euca:eucalyptus:CLUSTER01:cluster:cc_01/
SERVICE euare           eucalyptus      10.162.12.1     ENABLED     40      http://10.162.12.1:8773/services/Euare      arn:euca:eucalyptus::euare:10.162.12.1/`

Answer (score 3):

Faststart is not intended for use with larger installations:

> Eucalyptus Faststart is intended for smaller deployments. For larger
>   Eucalyptus deployments that require separation of components, see
>   Eucalyptus Installation or Eucalyptus HA Installation.

From:
https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#install-guide/faststart.html

You need to follow the regular installation documentation:

https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#install-guide/eucalyptus.html